# UIRefreshControl isn't working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

Adding `UIRefreshControl` in tableview as

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

This works in iOS 9.0 and prior, but it does not show in iOS 10.0.
Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: its working for me, You set refresh tint color.

Comment: it is already set but still not works.

Comment: It worked for me when
`[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` in viewDidLoad method